# Unable to use Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using `ASP.NET/C#` in `Visual Studio 2008`.I was trying to use `Crystal Reports` in my project.When I add Crystal Report.I can see `CrystalReport1.rpt` in my project but when I click on it.
Here is the image of my problem.

[image]

Can anybody help me out with this.I am not able to do anything further.

Do I need to re-install Crystal Report?

Any Links to install it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the .rpt file extension is not connected to the designer in VS. My guess is you need to re-install Crystal Reports.

Comment: You can google it. https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=visual%20studio%20crystal%20studio%20download&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=a0b504f6f844f4d8&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1097&bih=541

Answer (score 0):

You have to install/reinstall CrystalReports for Visual Studio

> Crystal Reports for Visual Studio is the custom version of Crystal
>   Reports that is available as part of the default installation in most
>   versions of Microsoft Visual Studio
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225592(v=vs.90).aspx

In Visual Studio click **Help\About Visual Studio** to find all installed components.
If it's not installed use original Visual Studio installer.

Comment: But how I have no previous experience with Crystal Reports.Any links?Thanks.